# Access function to match multiple criteria to multiple outputs (Or Excel)

Tags: excel, function, ms-access

I am wondering if there is a simple function that will be able to match certain criteria to various outputs. Quite hard to describe, but what I would want is something like:

```
=function([criteria],[output],[criteria],[output],......)
```

So for instance:

```
=function([SiteID]=1,"Global",[SiteID]=2,"IT",[SiteID]=3,"DE",[SiteID]=4,"NL",[SiteID]=5,"AU")
```

I know I can use `If` statements for this, but it makes it very complicated looking, was hoping there was a simple function for it, but is hard to search for as is complicated criteria.

This would ideally be for Access, but would be very useful in **Excel** as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach on the assumption you don't much care for my first offering:

In a full implementation of SQL you’d have access to `CASE` statements which allow something much closer to what you’re really wanting. I take it the real complaint against nested `IF` or `IIF` statements is how hard they are to read and maintain. However, you can use IF in a somewhat nonconventional way which you might find easier to read e.g.

```
=If(<condition1>,"Output 1","") &
 If(<condition2>,"Output 2","") &
 If(<condition3>,"Output 3","")
```

However, if more than one of the conditions are met you’ll get all of the outputs returned in the same cell/field,  with the nested `IF` approach you only get the output corresponding to the earliest condition to be met.  One way to get round that (there may be better) is to make all the outputs a standard length (pad them with spaces), and then wrap the entire thing in something like

```
=TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(<output from concatenated ifs as above>),<standardised length>))
```

Comment: This one is perfect! The first one was not exactly what I wanted, as I was hoping not to have to join. The creation of a function is great too (if it works, I didn't try it). But this unconventional workaround is exactly what I was looking for. If I write the conditions correctly then I can make sure they don't overlap, so no problem there. Thanks so much for your persistence here!

Comment: One thing to note is that because the outputs of the separate parts are concatenated, the output will always be a string, so if you are trying to output a number or date you may have to wrap the whole thing another function to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

## Original Answer for "Exact" Matches

In Excel, the natural way to achieve this is using a `VLOOKUP` function. In Access you'd join to a table. In both cases you want a table or range to store the translations:

```
+--------+----------+
| SiteID | SiteName |
+--------+----------+
|   1    |  Global  |
|   2    |    IT    |
|   3    |    DE    | 
|   4    |    NL    |
|   5    |    AU    |
+--------+----------+
```

### In Excel

```
=VLOOKUP( arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

**arg1**: The cell containing the value you wish to translate

**arg2**: The range holding the lookup table

**arg3**: The column number you wish to return from the lookup table. In this case 2.

**arg4**: The match type. You want to find an exact match so specifiy FALSE here (or zero)

### In Access

Create a new table called Sites in your database and add the relevant details. Now in your query window, bring in your source table containing the values to be looked up, and the new Site table. Click and Drag the field "SiteID" from the main table to the matching field on the new Site table. You can now add the column `SiteName` to your query.

## Edit: for interval matches rather than exact matches

### In Excel

In Excel, you can still use `VLOOKUP` for this. Here, I'm imagining a table like this:

```
+--------+------------------------------+
| Salary | CompanyCar                   |
+--------+------------------------------+
|      0 | No company car               |   
|  20000 | Access to shared company car | 
|  50000 | Own company car - basic      | 
| 100000 | Own company car - executive  |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

The figures in the first column are intended to act as thresholds, when an employee salary reaches the threshold, they get access to the relevant benefit. The first table in this column must be sorted "ascending".

Now use `VLOOKUP` as above but for argument 4:

**arg4**: The match type. It's not an exact match (not sure what to call it), so specifiy TRUE here (or 1)

### In Access

Add an extra column to the table:

```
+--------+------------------------------+------------+
| Salary | CompanyCar                   | UpperBound |
+--------+------------------------------+------------+
|      0 | No company car               |    20000   |
|  20000 | Access to shared company car |    50000   |
|  50000 | Own company car              |   100000   |
| 100000 | Executive level company car  |     NULL   |
+--------+------------------------------+------------+
```

Now instead of joining the two tables, simply have them "float" separately in the query window. This creates what's called a `CROSS JOIN`. We need to restrict the matches to just the relevant rows using a `WHERE` clause.

In the grid for the criteria add Salary and UpperBound. All the following criteria:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------+                               
| Salary              | UpperBound                    |   
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| <= [EmployeeSalary] | > [EmployeeSalary] or is null |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

In the SQL view this is equivalent to:

```
WHERE
Salary <=[EmployeeSalary] and
(UpperBound > [EmployeeSalary] or UpperBound is null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact the above example I gave was a simplifed version of what I want to do.

I would like a function like I described, as the criteria would be based values, so for instance:

=function([Revenue]>=50 And [Revenue]<=99.99,"Silver",[Revenue]>=100 And [Revenue]<499.99,"Gold",[Revenue]>500,"Platinum")

So was the answer to my question no, about that function existing, if the only way you suggest is using external data/tables for the simplified version?

Comment: Ah, okay. We can handle that too .. but need a slightly different approach. I'll work on a update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon a better answer to this. In the years since I stopped using MS Access, they introduced a new built in function. It works almost exactly like the one I created in the original version of this answer. It's called `SWTICH` Access only (*). It works like this:

```
Switch ( <condition1>, <output1> [,<condition2>, <output2> ... ] )
```

If no condition is met, it will return `NULL`. If you'd like a default (like an `ELSE`) just set the last condition/ouput pair `TRUE, <default output>`.

At the time of writing the Microsoft Support page for this function was [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379).

(*) Excel does have a function called `SWITCH`, but it does something else.

**My original answer - Still Relevant for Excel**

Ordinarily I'd update my previous answer, but in this case my answers have been very different from each other making that seem inappropriate.

Anyway, not wanting to be defeated by this question, I decided that I would try to write my own VBA function to do exactly what you requested. I'm not going to say it's perfect, but it worked nicely for me. Paste the following in a VBA module:

```
Function MULTI_IF(ParamArray Inputs()) As Variant

    Dim Output As Variant
    Output = False 'This is the output when no conditions are met

    For x = 0 To UBound(Inputs) - 1 Step 2

        On Error GoTo ErrorStep '<-- Added to prevent errors being thown for NULLs and other bad input
        If CBool(Inputs(x)) = True Then
            Output = Inputs(x + 1)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next x

    MULTI_IF = Output

    Exit Function        

ErrorStep:
    Inputs(x) = False '<-- Assume condition is false where it can't be converted to Boolean
    Resume

End Function
```

You should be able to use it from Excel exactly as you described. After trialling in Access, I added some error handling (see comments above) and included them in an edit here.

If none of the conditions are met, it will output `False`. You could alter that in the code or when you use the function implement an `Else` condition by making the final condition/output pair `...,TRUE,"Default Here")`.